# EPO Rest API for JSON response

Tags: angularjs, rest, jsonp

I am accessing the following REST Service to get my data.

http://ops.epo.org/3.1/rest-services/classification/cpc/search?q=Test

I have to use JSONP request. But the response there is in XML form. Even if I use callback=JSON_CALLBACK it doesn't make any difference.

And if I create my own callback method it always runs when all other processing is done. So that is of no use to me.

Please advice that how can I manage that?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try appending `.js` to the url, before the query parameters:

- [http://ops.epo.org/3.1/rest-services/classification/cpc/search**.js**?q=test](http://ops.epo.org/3.1/rest-services/classification/cpc/search.js?q=test)
- [http://ops.epo.org/3.1/rest-services/classification/cpc/search**.js**?q=test&callback=?](http://ops.epo.org/3.1/rest-services/classification/cpc/search.js?q=test&callback=?)